# copying parallel directories Why does cp -r work this way?

Tags: directory, cp

The following works correctly (ie does what I want)

```
 cd /var/www/release/
 mkdir wiki
 cp -rp ../html/wiki ./
```

However if I do (what seems more intuitive)

```
 cp -r ../html/wiki ./wiki
```

it will create /var/www/release/wiki/wiki  (what I never want)

This behaviour is the same with mv. I am hoping that someone will explain the logic behind this behaviour so I get it right first time in future

Comment: My interpretation is that, in `cp -r ../html/wiki ./wiki`, you're telling it to copy the directory itself into a directory named `wiki`. Since `wiki` exists, it copies it into there. You could alternatively use `cp -r ../html/wiki/* ./wiki` to tell it to copy the *files* into the directory.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to copy an entire directory as `SOURCE`, `cp` wants a directory as `DESTINATION`, to know where it should be stored.

The mistake you did was not removing the directory `/var/www/release/wiki` after your `mkdir` and `cp -rp ...` test.

So `cp -r ...` did, what you told it to do: Copy `../html/wiki` into the *existing* directory `./wiki` and thus creating another sub-directory called `wiki`.

Just remove `/var/www/release/wiki` and then do the `cp -r` command again, and you'll see it works as intended.

Comment: that works as you say but now I'm more confused!

Comment: @zzapper You did `mkdir ./wiki` and thus creating a `wiki` directory in `release`. Now you did tell `cp` to copy the directory `../html/wiki` and it's contents to `./wiki`. Another way to explain it: You have a source bin `../html/wiki`. You placed a bigger destination bin `./wiki` in `release`. Now you placed the bin `../html/wiki` including it's contents (apples/fish) inside of the bigger bin. Instead, you should have not placed a bigger bin in `release` and just moved/copied the source bin to `release`.

Comment: That's cleared up why there is differential behaviour I hadn't understood the concept of a bin

Answer (score 1):

There are 3 forms of `cp` and `mv`

```
cp/mv [OPTION]... [-T] SOURCE DEST
cp/mv [OPTION]... SOURCE... DIRECTORY
cp/mv [OPTION]... -t DIRECTORY SOURCE...
```

Form 1 and 2 are of form `cp/mv a b`, in form 2 `b` is a existing directory, but in form 1 `b` is a destination. To avoid this ambiguity do not use form 2. Use form 1 for what you are trying to do, with `-T`. Use form 3 to move or copy to an existing directory.

Answer (score 1):

When the last argument to `cp` is an existing directory, `cp` copies the source file(s) into that directory. `mv` does the same.

You would like to merge the source directory with the target directory. But that would only make sense when the source is a directory. So when you run `cp somefile existing-directory/`, you end up with `existing-directory/somefile`; and when you run `cp -r somedir existing-directory/` you end up with `existing-directory/somedir`. The behavior that you find intuitive (but which I don't) would require that `cp` makes a difference depending on whether the source is a directory or not, so `cp -r somefile somedir existing-directory/` would create `existing-directory/somefile` but not `existing-directory/somedir`.

`cp something existing-directory` copies the source into the target directory. If the source is a directory and you want to copy its contents, run

```
cp -rp something/* existing-directory/
```

Note that this omits [files whose name begins with a `.`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dot_file#Unix_and_Unix-like_environments). If you want to include them, an easy way is to use `rsync` instead:

```
rsync -a something/ existing-directory/
```

With `rsync`, if you put a `/` at the end of the source, then the source's content is copied into the destination directory. Without a trailing `/` on the source, the source is created as an entry in the destination directory.